# Define Custom error messages Flask Restful API

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am having problems defining my own error custom messages. I am not exactly sure if I am doing it correctly but I am trying to follow the documentation:

http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending.html#define-custom-error-messages

This is what my code looks like:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext import restful
myerrors = {
    'CannotFind':{
        'message':'We could not find it!',
        'status':404
    }
}
app = Flask(__name__)
api = restful.Api(app, errors = myerrors)
```

However when, I run this program i get an error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'
```

The docs says `Once your errors dictionary is defined, simply pass it to the Api constructor` thats what I did no?

I also noticed in the documentation they used:

```
api = flask_restful.Api(app, errors=errors)
```

so I thought I was using something incorrectly and therefore I tried to import that flask_restful but it doesn't exists...

So now I am confused, please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The version of flask-restful you get when you install with pip will be v0.2.12

This version does not have the `errors` keyword argument for `flask_restful.API.__init__` [(github link)](https://github.com/twilio/flask-restful/blob/0.2.12/flask_restful/__init__.py#L71)

To get the errors keyword you will need to install more recent code from github. There is instructions for how to do this on the [flask-restful installation page.](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)

**Edit:** As of 2014-11-23 this answer no longer applies because v0.3.0 of flask-restful was released and is on pypi.

Comment: Thanks, did they mention this in the doc? I couldn't find it.

Comment: I couldn't see any such info in the docs, no. I came to this conclusion from poking around the code and git repository.

Comment: Ah thats no good if they didn't write that anywhere :( Not happy about this. But thanks again.

Comment: I'm going to look into the Flask method described here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/apierrors/